# R comparing correlation matrices among two groups by stats (t-test)

Tags: r, matrix, statistics, correlation

I have two matrices:

```
cor_matrices1 = array(sample(100),dim=c(20,10,10))

cor_matrices2 = array(sample(100),dim=c(10,10,10))
```

cor_matrices1 has 20 documents and for each document we have a correlation matrix of 10 by 10 terms

cor_matrices2 has 10 documents and for each document we have a correlation matrix of 10 by 10 terms

The correlation matrices 10 by 10 have the same terms for all of them, just change the values.

I'd like to compare the terms of cor_matrices1 and cor_matrices2 by t-test.

The result is one correlation matrix 10x10 with the t-values.

Thanks

Comment: `cor_matrices1` is an array of 10 times 20x10 matrices. Did you intend to create 20 times 10x10 matrices?

Comment: no, cor_matrices1 is an array of 20 times 10x10 matrices. I would like to create one from the t-values between the two arrays among the 20 and 10 documents.

Answer (score 1):

So essentially you need the following: There might be better ways than a double for-loop but in this occasion I would prefer a double for-loop because it is clearer to read and as long as you don't have lots of matrices (10x20 are not many) then you are fine (this only took 1 second to compute).

First of all you will end up with a 20x10 matrix since the first array has 20 matrices and the second 10.

You need to do the following:

**Data:**

```
cor_matrices1 = array(sample(100),dim=c(20,10,10))
cor_matrices2 = array(sample(100),dim=c(10,10,10))
```

**Solution**

```
#initiate mymatrix as a 20x10 matrix 
mymatrix <- matrix(nrow=dim(cor_matrices1)[1], ncol=dim(cor_matrices2)[1])

#run the loop to populate the matrix with the t.tests' statistics
for ( i in 1:dim(cor_matrices1)[1]) {
  for ( j in 1:dim(cor_matrices2)[1]) {
    mymatrix[i,j] <- t.test(cor_matrices1[i,,], cor_matrices2[j,,])$statistic
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
> mymatrix
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]         [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
 [1,]  5.5853096  6.1979575  0.9636135  -0.38003497  0.8078331  3.3969073  1.5651130  6.1375357  -0.4856826  3.8526553
 [2,]  6.4835893  7.3883179  1.3936984  -0.06060466  1.2600229  4.1799857  2.0909319  7.2064851  -0.1804566  4.6040987
 [3,] 10.5499600 12.4612833  4.9087509   3.67337581  5.1053177  8.5639508  5.9404200 11.7967193   3.5041504  8.6115299
 [4,]  6.8099365  7.7779495  1.6835736   0.24432968  1.5720800  4.5265863  2.4031794  7.5666095   0.1212386  4.9265904
 [5,]  3.1313201  3.5382502 -1.8716670  -3.58258536 -2.2470268  0.5182614 -1.3648099  3.5951168  -3.6751691  1.1924479
 [6,] -2.1215144 -2.6120967 -7.9545278 -10.82110795 -9.0923043 -6.0319761 -7.8460891 -2.0551756 -10.8493623 -4.5923672
 [7,]  0.5649513  0.5971889 -3.8604264  -5.46406280 -4.2873721 -1.9296771 -3.4898817  0.8036567  -5.5374016 -1.2016093
 [8,]  2.3410299  2.6510613 -2.7448643  -4.57137186 -3.1979002 -0.4049241 -2.2798867  2.7594448  -4.6578399  0.3470886
 [9,] -1.0873533 -1.2121674 -5.2500287  -6.81509337 -5.7070461 -3.5289496 -4.9454641 -0.9462123  -6.8790254 -2.7761814
[10,] 11.6457024 13.3988664  6.3944924   5.36168846  6.6623806  9.8549618  7.4104395 12.8070217   5.1956504  9.8589128
[11,]  0.6202717  0.6448094 -3.2380057  -4.55523337 -3.5532787 -1.5135278 -2.8796109  0.8239709  -4.6256268 -0.9112790
[12,]  0.8312961  0.8860768 -3.4505211  -4.96191790 -3.8328582 -1.5512273 -3.0714358  1.0739395  -5.0362201 -0.8703299
[13,]  6.0480378  6.6406437  1.6431224   0.41111323  1.5305889  3.9923199  2.2400048  6.5800061   0.3066747  4.4044122
[14,]  3.7185897  3.9910684 -0.2165576  -1.40970887 -0.4069604  1.7259251  0.2460738  4.0586111  -1.4943193  2.2070542
[15,]  3.6257669  3.9953318 -0.8952537  -2.33610856 -1.1590954  1.3223841 -0.3895172  4.0462200  -2.4282655  1.8871558
[16,] -1.1606132 -1.3436360 -6.0074059  -7.99304170 -6.6575927 -4.1054003 -5.7273085 -1.0090346  -8.0535361 -3.1485593
[17,] -3.6306778 -4.1709216 -8.5889634 -10.86913291 -9.4628367 -6.9216143 -8.4516457 -3.6551922 -10.9088895 -5.7360407
[18,] -1.6046036 -1.8704075 -6.6534574  -8.81815316 -7.4052207 -4.7544755 -6.4115234 -1.4825538  -8.8725847 -3.6947929
[19,]  3.2956127  3.5441625 -0.7047402  -1.94573896 -0.9211169  1.2430949 -0.2505359  3.6261504  -2.0294596  1.7518654
[20,]  5.2945216  5.7533496  1.1045595  -0.09728864  0.9666110  3.2797497  1.6473487  5.7459609  -0.1936377  3.7147684
```